# Dot Net Nuke Compliation error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, dotnetnuke

I am getting this error when attempting to install Dot Net nuke.

CS0103: The name 'Localization' does not exist in the current context

```
  this.confirmPasswords = function () {
           if ($('#<%= txtPassword.ClientID %>')[0].value != $('#<%= txtConfirmPassword.ClientID %>')[0].value) {

$('#<%= lblAdminInfoError.ClientID %>').text('<%= Localization.GetSafeJSString(LocalizeString("PasswordMismatch"))%>');
                $("#continueLink").addClass('dnnDisabledAction');
           } else {
```

the error happens on the line of $('#<%= lblAdminInfoError.ClientID %>').text

Are there any permissions i need to fix or any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Which package are you using? The INSTALL or SOURCE package? I highly recommend INSTALL

Comment: In that case, one thing I would suggest is making sure that you UNBLOCK the ZIP file before extracting it, as Windows tends to block DLLs from ZIP files and that can cause problems.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that and recieved the same error.

Comment: Hrmmm what version of DNN are you installing, and what operating system are you on? What version of the .NET framework?

Comment: newest dnn, windows server 2008 r2. we have the app pool set to 4.0 it allows 4 and 4.5